# i cannot access objects inside of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i have created an object and i am passing an array  and  different objects to that array  , but i cannot access them , it always gives , 0 is undefined or undefined when i want to access element at specific index , also even though there are more then 150 objects inside this array it still gives this message :
length: 194
**proto**: Array(0)

so i think array is empty .
[image: result of console.log(data) on last line of code]

```
    let passglobaldataArraytofun = (countryNames) => {
  let objforeachCountryStatistics = {};
  objforeachCountryStatistics.countries = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < countryNames.length; index++) {
    axios
      .get(`https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/${countryNames[index]}`)
      .then((res) => {
        objforeachCountryStatistics.countries.push(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
  let data = objforeachCountryStatistics;
  console.log(data);
};
```

second method

```
async function passglobaldataArraytofun(countryNames){
  let objforeachCountryStatistics = {};
  objforeachCountryStatistics.countries = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < countryNames.length; index++) {
   let res= await axios.get(`https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/${countryNames[index]}`)
     
objforeachCountryStatistics.countries.push(res.data);
     
     
  }
  console.log(objforeachCountryStatistics)
};
```

Comment: The above comment explains your problem but in a general way. Your code has 2 problems: 1) You are resetting your `globalArrayForstoringeachCountryandItsStatistics` every iteration of your loop and 2) Because `axios.get` is an asynchronous call, the result won't be available immediately after calling it. When you `console.log(data)` the promises will not have resolved yet and thus not have any data in them.

Comment: @nbokmans thanks,actually i am getting response but i want it to be in specific format thats why i am pushing it to an array and that array is a property in an  object.

Comment: @nbokmans yess u are right i took the code line globalArrayForstoringeachCountryandItsStatistics.countries=[] out of the loop

Comment: you need to apply() the push(), otherwise they all go in index 0

Comment: @dandavis thanks , if u have time can u just make quick changes to the code?

Comment: I don't want to leave you hanging without an answer and the question was closed. You are very close in your second function, just have to get the response json. Excuse the formatting: `passglobaldataArrayToFun = async countryNames => { 
    const countryDataRequests = countryNames.map(name => axios.get('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/' + name).then(response => response.json()));
    const countryDataResponses = await Promise.all(countryDataRequests);

    console.log(countryDataResponses);
    return countryDataResponses;
}`

Comment: @nbokmans dude thanks alot ,  i ran ur code  but still i was getting the error res.json is not a function.

Comment: Disregard that comment, `fetch` is not supported in `nodejs`, so instead replace just the `const countryDataRequests = ...` line with this: `const countryDataRequests = countryNames.map(name => axios.get('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/' + name).then(response => response.data));`

Comment: @nbokmans   thanks for ur time but the last method that u suggested is exctly the same i use in my code  , and i was getting all the responses , then i only wanted to store them in an array called countries  which was property in an object called  objforeachCountryStatistics , it all worked when i console.log it but i was just unable to access these objects. and even i had more than 150 objects in array its showd  prototype Array(0)

Comment: @nbokmans  u can also view the final  data that i got , in the image i provided.